# How can I combine those two loops into one?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I want to combine this two loops to one:

```
for (int i = 7; i <=100; i+=10) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(i); 
} 

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i+=7)  
{   
   Console.WriteLine(i); 
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is what you're trying to do

```
for (int i = 0; i<= 100; i++)
{
    if (i%7==0 || i%10==7) 
       Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: and yours gives exact results of the question?

Comment: No it doesn't. It combines the results of the two loops. Just like he asked.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i <=100; i++)  {
   if(i%7 == 0 || i%10 == 0)
       Console.WriteLine (i); 
}
```

or using LINQ:

```
Enumerable.Range(0,100).Where(i => i%7 == 0 || i%10 == 0).ToList()
.ForEach(i=> {Console.WriteLine (i); });
```

If you want duplicate results too:

```
for (int i = 0; i <=100; i++)  {
   if(i%7 == 0) Console.WriteLine (i); 
   if(i%10 == 0 && i!=0)  Console.WriteLine (i); 
} 

    Enumerable.Range(7,100)   
.Where(i => i%10 == 0).ToList().AddRange(
Enumerable.Range(0,100)   
.Where(i => i%7 == 0).ToList())
    .ForEach(i=> {Console.WriteLine (i); });
```

Comment: What about i=0 within the second loop it wont be displayed

Comment: This is not the same result as the question. The first loop prints 7, 17, 27, etc. the second loop prints 0, 7, 14, etc. your loop doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds stupid but it does exactly what you want. It looks not neat because it preserves the order of the values printed just like your example:

```
bool flag = false;
int factor = 10;
for (int i = 7; i < 100;)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);

    i += factor;
    if ( i >= 100)
    {
        if (flag)
            break;
        flag = true;
        factor = 7;
        i = 0;
    }

}
```

It uses a Boolean flag and a dynamic factor to do the two passed in one loop.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you are really trying to do but if it me and I want to print number I would use math formula

```
var i = 0;
while(true)
{
    var x = 7 + (i * 10);
    if(x < 100)
         Console.WriteLine(x);

    var y = i * 7;
    Console.WriteLine(y);
    if(y >= 100)
         break;
    i++;
}
```